# Extracting images from a PDF using PyPDF2 - but the pdf has no metadata

Tags: pypdf, pdfminer

The PDF is a scanned image, so there is no way I have found yet, to pull out the images. I have tried methods including crop and media boxes, but it pulls the entire pages as images. I have also tried other parsing libraries like pdfminer.six, but the entire page is pulled as a result.

I tried using media and cropboxes in hopes it would grab the image as specified but it pulls the entire page instead.

Answer (score 0):

If the document is scanned, the whole page is a single image. So all libraries will give you that.

As the maintainer of pypdf and PyPDF2, I can tell you that there is no way around that.

If you want the illustrations within an image file, you need machine learning. Our using an image cropping tool.